# Select and deselect issue in select option with checkboxes using jquery

Tags: jquery

I am using Materialized theme where select option with checboxes just add multiple attribute in select tag.

```
<div class="input-field col s3"><label for="batchid">Batch</label>
   <select id="batchid" data-rel="chosen" name="batchid[]" class="form-control" multiple> 
       <option value="All" selected>All Batches</option>
       <option value="1" selected>Batch01</option>
       <option value="2" selected>Batch02</option>
   </select>   
</div>
```

I am doing that When user select **All Batches** then if other else options are selected so it will be deselect and when **Batch01** or other options are select then **All Batches** will be deselect

Here is the layout image of select option with checboxes
[image: select option with checboxes]

Bydefault **All Batches** are select when I select **Batch01** or other option  then **All Batches** is deselect and **Batch01** or other option select.

Issue is that When select **All Batches** then **Batch01** is not deselect

here is the code of jquery

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){ 
 $("#batchid").change(function(){
 var batchid = $(this).val();
 var str_bat = batchid.toString(); 
 if(str_bat.search("All")!=-1){
if(str_bat.search(",")!=-1){ 
    $('#batchid option[value=All]').prop('selected', false);    
    var res1 = str_bat.split(",");  
     if(res1[1]!='' && (res1[0]!='All' ||res1[0]=='All')){
        $('#batchid option[value='+res1[1]+']').prop('selected', true);     
        $('select').material_select();          
        $('#batchid option[value=All]').prop('selected', false);
        $('select').material_select();
    }
    else if(res1[0]=='All' && (res1[1]!='' || res1[1]=='')){
        $('#batchid option[value=All]').prop('selected', true);
        $('select').material_select();
        $('#batchid option[value='+res[1]+']').prop('selected', false);
        $('select').material_select();          
    } else {

    }

  } else {
     alert("ALL Check");
    $("#batchid option").each(function(i){
       $('#batchid option[value='+$(this).val()+']').prop('selected', false);
       $('select').material_select();
    });
    $('#batchid option[value=All]').prop('selected', true); 
    $('select').material_select();  
}
} 
 if(str_bat.search(",")!=-1){ 
$('#batchid option[value=All]').prop('selected', false);
    var res = str_bat.split(",");   
    //alert(res[0]+' '+res[1]);
     if(res[1]!='' && res[0]!='All'){
        $('#batchid option[value='+res[1]+']').prop('selected', true);      
        $('select').material_select();          
        $('#batchid option[value=All]').prop('selected', false);
        $('select').material_select();
    } if(res[0]=='All' && res[1]==''){
        $('#batchid option[value=All]').prop('selected', true);
        $('select').material_select();
        $('#batchid option[value='+res[1]+']').prop('selected', false);
        $('select').material_select();          
    } 
    }
 });
 });
```

If I alert(str_bat); then array format like this way All,1,2

Comment: If you select "all batches" the other options will automatically checked? and if I deselect 1 of the other choices, "all batches" will be unchecked, is this what you mean?

Comment: I think, it would be better to use check-boxes with same name (`name="batchid[]"`) instead of `select` control.

Comment: @MarkGerrylMirandilla.... I mean that If I select All Batches then other option if selected already so they will b deselect

Comment: and if I select Batch01 or batch02 then All Batches will be deselect if it is already checked

Answer (score 0):

do you want to do this?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  //when document is ready All Batches option is only selected bydefault and other options are deselect.
  $('#batchid > option[value="All"]').prop('selected',true); 
  $('#batchid > option[value!="All"]').prop('selected',false);  

 $('#batchid').change(function(){
  
    var $selected = $(this).val().toString().split(',');
    $('#batchid > option').prop('selected',false);
    $.each($selected,function(i,item){
      $('#batchid > option[value="'+item+'"]').prop('selected',true);    
    });
   
    //When I select All Batches option then Batch01 option will be deselected
    if($('#batchid > option[value="All"]:selected').length > 0)
    {
        $('#batchid > option[value!="All"]').prop('selected',false);
    };
    
    //When I select Batch01 option then All Batches option will be deselected
    if($('#batchid > option[value!="All"]:selected').length > 0)
    {
        $('#batchid > option[value="All"]').prop('selected',false); 
    };
      
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="input-field col s3"><label for="batchid">Batch</label>
   <select id="batchid" data-rel="chosen" name="batchid[]" class="form-control" multiple> 
       <option value="All">All Batches</option>
       <option value="1">Batch01</option>
       <option value="2">Batch02</option>
   </select>   
</div>
```

Comment: If I alert($currentVal) then show an array format like this way All,1

Comment: @Arslan you can use the $allValues

Comment: @Arslan sorry, i am trying to help. try again.

Comment: I am tried your code its working little bit not fully working way

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181218/discussion-between-arslan-and-tdayi).